# Unable to set up CloudFront Distribution: "The parameter originPath is null."

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I can't figure out what field is invalid.

I've created a distribution before and everything went swimmingly.

Comment: I'm also having this issue right now using an S3 bucket as the origin.

Answer (score 0):

AWS rolled out new features for CloudFront and they must have goofed and rolled out stricter validation for a field that didn't exist at the time.

Everything is functioning as normal now.